# What does this function return

Tags: lua, variadic-functions

```
function f(...)
  return ...
end
```

And I call it like this:

```
f()
```

Example

```
a = f()
print(a) -- echoes 'nil', same as print(nil)
```

But

```
print(f()) -- echoes newline, same as print(), that is, no args
t = {f()} -- same as t = {}
```

So, what does f() return?

Update: did not know that functions can return 'void', found this http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-09/msg00289.html meanwhile.

Comment: "functions can return 'void'" Yes (what do you think `print` returns) and no (you can always use the results of a function in an expression list; the compiler has no way of knowing what a function returns) and maybe (a function doesn't have to return a list with the same number values every time it is called). I don't "void" is a very good description of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns all parameters you called it with.

```
f() -- has no parameter, returns nothing
```

If you do an assignment with less values than you have variables, i.e.

```
local a, b = 3
local c
```

Then that'll just end up with b and c being nil.

On the other hand, this would all do something:

```
f(1) -- returns 1
f(1, 2, 3) -- returns 1, 2 and 3
local t = {f(1, 2, 3)} -- table with the values 1, 2 and 3
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer regarding the type could be the output of this command:

```
print(type(f()))
```

In this case, it prints:

```
bad argument #1 to 'type' (value expected)
```

So, a value is expected, but there is no value. => It returns **nothing** (void).

So, it's a normal behaviour to have: `t = {f()}` <=> `t = {}`

Regarding the assignment, Lua assigns by default the `nil` value if there is **no value**.

Answer (score 2):

I found that Lua function can return 'nothing', not even a nil. In this case, `f()` returns `nothing`. Using `nothing` (without assignment) results in zero arguments in another function call(like `print(f())` or in table constructor(`{f()}`).

`print(a)` echoed nil because `a` had no assigned value, `print(any_name)` will echo nil aswell.

Comment: A function always returns a list of values. A function can have zero or more return statements, each of which returns a list of zero or more values. If a function ends without executing a return statement, it returns a list of no values. You've looked at passing a list of values to another function (print), a table constructor ({}), and (in your question) a return statement.

Comment: My addition to this comment: when a function is called there are function arguments on the stack. When a function returns, there are results on the stack. So there could be zero values on the stack, "nothing". In this case, print will not output any value. 
After `f()` call there are zero values on the stack. And this stack is then passed to `print` call.